# Parse recurrence rule data

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object in the following format:

```
const input = {
  "recurrence": {
    "rrule": [
      "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20230606T133000Z"
    ],
  }
};
```

I want to extract the value of `FREQ` to check if its value is `DAILY` or `YEARLY` and to get the value of `UNTIL` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may look like this:

```js
const
   input = {
    "recurrence": {
      "rrule": [
        "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20230606T133000Z"
      ],
    }
  },
  parts = input.recurrence.rrule[0].split(';'),
  isDaily = parts[0].split('=')[1] === 'DAILY',
  untilValue = parts[1].split('=')[1];

console.log({
  isDaily,
  untilValue
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex here to extract the value of FREQ and UNTIL from string.

```js
const input = {
  "recurrence": {
    "rrule": [
      "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20230606T133000Z"
    ],
  }
};

const rrule = input.recurrence.rrule[0];
const freqMatch = rrule.match(/FREQ=([^;]+)/);
const untilMatch = rrule.match(/UNTIL=([^;]+)/);

if (freqMatch) {
  const freqValue = freqMatch[1];
  if (freqValue === "DAILY") {
    console.log("Frequency is DAILY");
  } else if (freqValue === "YEARLY") {
    console.log("Frequency is YEARLY");
  }
}

if (untilMatch) {
  const untilValue = untilMatch[1];
  console.log("UNTIL value:", untilValue);
}
```